# Rails doens't show css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, html, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i'm new in Rails and in Rails 4 i have generated a controller Pages.
The generator process have created a

```
 app/stylesheets/pages.css.scss
```

Inside this scss file i've inserted:

```
.center { text-align: center;}
```

When i launch the web app, in the html source code i found

```
 <link href="/assets/pages.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">
```

but this css is empty and not applies style.

Anyone can help me?
Thanks

Comment: This is not how assets works. You need to read Rails guide. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good in your code. Maybe you precompiled your assets? How did you run your server?

Try doing `rake assets:clean` before `rails server` to clean any precompiled assets that may exist.